# calcular diferença timestamp entre duas datas

Tags: javascript

Tenho duas datas, por exemplo: 01/01/2001 e 01/01/2002. A diferenca entre eles é de um ano. Como posso calcular essa diferenca e se for superior a um ano fazer um print.

Answer (score 1):

É só adicionar essa função ao seu Javascript:

```
function dataDif(data1, data2){
   data1 = data1.split("/");
   data2 = data2.split("/");
   dif = Math.abs(parseInt(data1[0])-parseInt(data2[0]));
   dif += parseInt(Math.abs(parseInt(data1[1])*30.41 - parseInt(data2[1])*30.41));
   dif += parseInt(Math.abs(parseInt(data1[2]) - parseInt(data2[2]))*365);

   return dif;
}
```

E a utilize desta forma:

```
dif = dataDif("01/01/2001", "01/01/2002");
if(dif > 365){
   //Suas ações
}
```

Essa função eu mesmo fiz. Ela retorna a diferença entre as duas datas em dias.
Ou seja, é só você checar se a diferença for maior que 365 para saber se há uma diferença maior que 1 ano.
Até.

Answer (score 1):

Ao mexer com datas aconselho a usar a biblioteca [Momenjs](http://momentjs.com/), pois ela faz todo trabalho 'pesado' envolvendo cálculo de datas.

Com ela você pode usar a função [`diff()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) para calcular a diferença entre datas.

Exemplo:

```js
var data1 = moment("01-02-2001", "DD-MM-YYYY");
var data2 = moment("01-01-2002", "DD-MM-YYYY");
var diferenca = data2.diff(data1, "years", true);

if (diferenca > 1) {
  document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML = "Mais de 1 ano";
} else if (diferenca == 1) {
  document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML = "Exatamente 1 ano";
} else {
  document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML = "Menos de 1 ano";
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="saida"></div>
```